# question related to type of row of UITabelView

Tags: iphone

how to use UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle and UITableViewCellStyleValue2 in 1 row   with cell's   text property   not UILabel

Comment: What is your question? It is difficult to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[cell textLabel] setText:@"Main Line of Text"];
[[cell detailTextLabel] setText:@"Subtitle Here"];
```